# jquery val function gets the old value from textarea

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, textarea, html-helper

I want to reject the bulk records with remarks. I used the 'textarea' tag for getting the user's comments when the user clicks on the reject button on the page.

The problem is when I type some remarks and click the Ok button in the prompt, I can't get the value of the commenting textarea. The value is null. When I close the prompt, and do this process again, I get the value of the textarea before what I entered. The jquery code is written in the HtmlHelper class file.

Here are the jquery functions:

```
       $('#{0}BulkRejection').click(function () {{
                var selectedRowId = $('#{0}').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedRowId.length; i++) {{
                    cellValue = $('#{0}').jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId[i], '{3}');
                    var ch =  jQuery('#{0}').find('#'+selectedRowId[i]+' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');

                    if(ch)
                    {{
                        stringArray[i + 1] = cellValue;
                    }}
                }}
                if (stringArray.length == 0) {{
                    alert('No Record Selected');
                    return false;
                }}

                var execute = function () {{
                    alert($('#AuthRemarks').find('textarea.form-control').val() + '-' +$('#AuthRemarks').val())       

                    if ($('#AuthRemarks').val() == '') {{

                        alert('Enter the Reject Remarks');
                        $('#AuthRemarks').focus();
                    }}
                    else {{
                        $(this).dialog('close')
                        stringArray[0] = $('#AuthRemarks').val();
                        var postData = {{ values: stringArray }};
                        $.ajax({{

                            type: 'POST',                                                                
                            url: RootUrlName+'/{5}',
                            data: postData,
                            success: function (data) {{
                                alert(data.Result);
                            }},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            traditional: true
                        }});



                    $('<div title=""Confirm Box""></div>').dialog({{
                        open: function () {{
                            $(this).html('<font color=""Green"">Record(s) Rejected Successfully</font>');
                        }},
                        close: function () {{

                            $(this).remove();
                            window.location.href = RootUrlName+'/{2}'   
                        }},
                        resizable: false,
                        height: 170,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {{
                            'Ok': function () {{
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                window.location.href = RootUrlName+'/{2}'  
                            }}

                        }}
                    }});
                 }}

                }}
                var cancel = function () {{
                    $(this).dialog('close')

                }}
                var dialogOpts = {{
                    buttons: {{
                        'Ok': execute,
                        'Cancel': cancel
                    }}
                }};
                if (confirm('Are you sure to reject this record(s)?')) {{
                    $('#dialog').dialog(dialogOpts);
                }}
            }});
        }});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class='panel-body'>
   <div id='dialog' ' title='Reject Remarks' style='display: none'>                                           

     <textarea class='form-control'  rows='5'  id='AuthRemarks' 
        maxlength='250' ></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

So It shows the "Enter The Reject Remarks" message even if I enter reject remarks and click the Ok button, Because the field "AuthRemarks" value is null(Refer the below given line). It is not working for the first time only.

```
  if ($('#AuthRemarks').val() == '') {{
      alert('Enter the Reject Remarks');
      $('#AuthRemarks').focus();
  }}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another element on your page with the id AuthRemarks?

Comment: I am sure, There is no other element with the id AuthRemarks.

Answer (score 0):

I had recent faced a similar Issue.
Make sure that the **BulkRejection Reject button** on which user is clicking 
is of the **type="button"**.

It could be that in your form it is of the 
**type="reset"** which could be resetting the form and changing all fields to their default value and comments field to null before the jquery function execution.